# Using smartphone as game controller for the GBA emulator on a tablet

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, emulators

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 with a GBA emulator.

How do I use my T-Mobile Concord Android smartphone as the game controller? I downloaded BTcontroller and the GBA controller setup, but I am not able to connect for some reason.

Do I need another app on the tablet to receive control signals?